# Adding custom class objects to list showing ambiguity

Tags: java, forms, list, action, struts-1

This is a sample test code I wrote to ensure what I know is right

```
class Form {
    List<Sample> samples;
    List<Sample> sampleList;
    public List<Sample> getSamples() {
        return samples;
    }
    public void setSamples(List<Sample> samples) {
        this.samples = samples;
    }
    public List<Sample> getSampleList() {
        return sampleList;
    }
    public void setSampleList(List<Sample> sampleList) {
        this.sampleList = sampleList;
    }
    void setInitialData() {
        this.samples = new ArrayList<Sample>();
        this.sampleList = new ArrayList<Sample>();
    }
}

class Sample {

}

public class ListAddingAmbiguity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.setInitialData();
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        form.getSamples().add(sample);
        form.getSampleList().add(sample);
        System.out.println(form.getSamples().size());
        System.out.println(form.getSampleList().size());
    }
}
```

The output coming is

```
1
1
```

And it is correct, `samples` and `sampleList` are two different references pointing to two different memory locations, so adding to `samples` won't change the size of `sampleList`.

But in my project code it is different, this is my `Form` class

```
public class InvoiceForm extends BaseActionForm {
    private List<ProductTO> products;
    private List<ProductTO> productList;
    // getters and setters
}
```

This is the code in my `Action` class

```
private void setProductsToInvoice(InvoiceForm invoiceForm) throws Exception {

        if(invoiceForm.getProducts() != null && !invoiceForm.getProducts().isEmpty()){
            ProductTO productTO = new ProductTO();//ProductEntryHandler.getInstance().prepareProductsForInvoice();
            invoiceForm.getProducts().add(productTO);
            invoiceForm.getProductList().add(productTO);
        }else {
            List<ProductTO> productTOs = new ArrayList<ProductTO>();
            productTOs.add(ProductEntryHandler.getInstance().prepareProductsForInvoice());
            invoiceForm.setProducts(productTOs);
            invoiceForm.setProductList(productTOs);
        }
    }
```

Both the products and productList are having a size of `1` initially, so in the above code `if block` will execute. The commented portion is the earlier code. Even if it is the new code `ProductTO productTO = new ProductTO();` or the old code `ProductTO productTO = ProductEntryHandler.getInstance().prepareProductsForInvoice();` the problem is the same.

Like I said when execution comes to the method both the lists are having a size of `1`. When the line `invoiceForm.getProducts().add(productTO);` is executed the size of `products` and `productList` size becomes `2`, which is in conflict with my test code. Now when the nest line `invoiceForm.getProductList().add(productTO);` is executed both the list size is becoming `3`. I don't know why its happening, can anybody help?

Comment: You are retrieving the list object and adding the element in it. It will definetly increase the size.

Comment: @Kick I have edited my test code but the output for test is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code `else` case in `setProductsToInvoice` set both `products` and `productList` to the **same list**:

```
List<ProductTO> productTOs = new ArrayList<ProductTO>();
productTOs.add(ProductEntryHandler.getInstance().prepareProductsForInvoice());
invoiceForm.setProducts(productTOs);
invoiceForm.setProductList(productTOs);
```

The correct way, or at least the less incorrect way, is something like this:

```
ProductTO newProd = 
    ProductEntryHandler.getInstance().prepareProductsForInvoice());
invoiceForm.setProducts(new ArrayList<ProductTO>());
invoiceForm.getProducts().add(newProd);

invoiceForm.setProductList(new ArrayList<ProductTO>());
invoiceForm.getProductList().add(newProd);
```

I'd suggest an investigation to determine why there are two lists apparently being maintained in parallel in the first place.  At first glance, it has a bit of a smell to it...

Comment: you were right I was feeding the same list to both the references and which was causing the problem